# Getting the specific date of a specific day in mySQL

Tags: mysql

is there anyway that I can get the specific date of a specific day in a week?

For example, I would like to get the date of Wednesday this week or Friday next week.

Is there a query that I can use to get the specific dates of the days mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Use SRSS inbuilt function

```
=WEEKDAYNAME(DATEPART("dw", Fields!myDate.Value)
```

OR

```
=WEEKDAYNAME(DATEPART("w", Fields!myDate.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this,

```
select date_add(now(), interval -30 day)
```

The above code will get you the date and time of exactly a month ago.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "The above code will get you the date and time of exactly a month ago." Unless, of course, the current month happens to have more or fewer days then 30...

Comment: Yeah of course, then you can alter the '-30' to which specific day you want, like I just changed it to '2 day' and it generated 4th Novemeber 2015.